# Network requests not showing up in cypress command log

Tags: cypress

We are trying to write a cypress test that checks one of the xhr requests made from the page. However the requests that we are making are not showing up in the command log. They do however show up in the bash console after running `cypress open`.

Command log:
[image]

Bash console:
[image]

- We have tried running our simple test against other domains such as cypress.io, and google.com. Requests show up just fine.
- We have verified that the requests made are not fetch requests.
- We have disabled `chomeWebSecurity` (not sure if relevant).

Here is the example we are using:

```js
describe('example', () => {
  it('visits a page', () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route('POST', '**');

    cy.visit('https://www.academia.edu/12297791/Open_Access_Meets_Discoverability_Citations_to_Articles_Posted_to_Academia.edu');
  });
});
```

Here is our `cypress.json` file:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

We are running cypress version 3.4.1

I would expect the command log to have these post requests show up, like this documentation describes: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Requests

Any help is greatly appreciated, as we're unsure how else to debug this.

Comment: Is this still a problem? II tried your example but was not able to load the page in chrome.

Comment: @JosefBiehler, it continued to be a problem so we switched to testcafe without figuring out the route cause. You were not able to load the page? It seems to load fine for me with Chrome 79.0.3945.88 on OSX 10.14.6.

Comment: now it works. maybe a temporary network problem. Does not matter now, as you have switched to testcafe :-)

Answer (score 0):

1.) I would suggest to use a more up-to-date version of Cypress with the cy.intercept().

2.) A typical problem can be the timing - add a cy.wait(X) before it, or add a timeout to replace the default timeout.

3.) Make sure the path of the route/intercept, especially when it differs from the cy.visit() 's url.

4.) Additional hint, use aliases.